# Get all Cucumber tags in java

Tags: java, tags, cucumber

I've found the following documentation for the cucumber tags
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks
, but I when I tried to use them (in IntelliJ IDEA), some of them are not appeard in the IDE. If I ask for the avaliable commands after the '@' in the feature file, there are the main (Scenario: , Scenario outline: , Scenario template: , Give, Background, And, But, Then, When) tags, but nothing like *AfterStep*, or *Around* or *AfterConfiguration* which could useful to me later.
I know the page's samples have been written in ruby, but I would like to implement it in java. Unfortunately the cucumber's own page is still not quite well updated in the java section, the Hooks and Tagged hooks parts of it still under TODO.
https://cucumber.io/docs/reference#tagged-hooks

Comment: would this be useful? http://www.zsoltfabok.com/blog/2012/09/cucumber-jvm-hooks/

Comment: I've found this site earlier, but it still not tells anything about the missing tags/hooks.

Comment: you place hooks in the glue (java StepDefs), not in the specification.

Comment: so there is no need to tag them in the feature file, I just have to put the tag(s) and it's task(s) in the step definition?

Comment: No luck, the IDE still not accept these tags in the StepDefinition java file.

Comment: please check official examples: https://github.com/mgurov/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/examples/java-calculator-testng/src/test/java/cucumber/examples/java/calculator/RpnCalculatorStepdefs.java#L39

Comment: I cannot tell what you are trying to do, therefore I cannot reproduce your problem nor give a solution.

Comment: The wiki you are reading describes functionality that is available in Cucumber Ruby, but not in Cucumber java. Specifically: AfterStep,  Around and AfterConfiguration are not available in Cucumber java, which is why you cannot use them in your IDE. If you would like to implement them, you can find the Cucumber java project on Github: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm